# python3: List, Tuples including RegEx

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with lists and tuples in python3. I also have regular expressions and I would like to return firstname and lastname from a regex:

```
def Regex(list):
    rs=[]

    import re

    firstname = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]*(?!n)',list)

    lastname = re.findall(r'\*[A-Za-z]*',list)

    name = (firstname,lastname)

    rs.append(list(name))
    return rs
```

And I call the function here and would like to print the lastname:

```
##some data
filedata ="......"

for first,last in Regex(filedata ):
    print(last)
```

All I get is the message:

`<map object at 0xb6f8cb4c>`

I would like to have a list of tuples like

`[("Pete","Pose"),("Mark","Maisner"),(...,...)]`

I am not sure if this is right with splitting lastname and firstname and how I append these tuples to my list so I can access it.

Comment: there is definitely something else going on here, you would only get a `map` object if something in your code is using the `map` builtin.

Comment: What does the string `filedata` look like? Does it have any delimiters in it that separate the names? Is it just a sequential list of names like "Pete Pose Mark Maisner ..."?